# Is using multiple continuous integration services for a single project a good idea?

Tags: github, continuous-integration

Currently there's plenty of CI services available like CodeShip, CircleCI and Travis and also other services to check dependencies, security, etc

Using a CI and other services that check other software quality apart from testing makes sense, but it's also possible for a single project to use multiple CI services which will execute the same tests.

---

**What are the advantages and disadvantages of using multiple CI services for a single project?**

**Is there anyone using multiple CI's for a single project?**

This can be on GitHub, BitBucket or any other code hosting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather off-topic on SO, maybe better suited on [Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions) or the [proposed DevOps](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/97295/devops?referrer=cZS_mCq3NdL7h376hrOevQ2) (if/when successful) sister SE sites.

I see advantages:

- can cover combinations of verifications which a single CI system might not be able to, for one reason or another (typically technical reasons)
- the project might be shared by multiple teams/individuals having different interests/methodologies/CI system preferences/requirements

I see disadvantages:

- pollution of the VCS label/tag space, even potential conflicts
- extra costs for each CI system